# multiple tasks using same timer for different double interval value

Tags: c#

Please consider below test program.
I have three tasks with specific interval. [task1-- task1Interval  , [task2-- task2Interval , [task3-- task3Interval]
I want to use single timer to execute all three tasks.
Every thing works fine when interval is in integer. 
we want to achieve the same functionality with double interval values for e.g [task1Interval-- 0.1  , [task2Interval-- 2.1 , [task3Interval-- 3.1].

Any pointers for the same would be highly appreciated.

```
public class Class1
{
    private System.Timers.Timer _timer;
    private int _counter=0;
    private int task1Interval = 1;
    private int task2Interval = 2;
    private int task3Interval = 3;

    public void Start()
    {
        this._timer = new System.Timers.Timer(100);
        this._timer.AutoReset = true;
        this._timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.serviceTimerElapse);
        this._timer.Enabled = true;
        this._timer.Start();
    }

    private void serviceTimerElapse(object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        this._counter++;
        if (this._counter % task1Interval == 0)
        {
            task1();    
        }
        if (this._counter % task2Interval == 0)
        {
            task2();
        }
        if (this._counter % task3Interval == 0)
        {
            task3();
        }
    }
    private void task1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("task1 started");

    }
    private void task2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("task2 started");

    }
    private void task3()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("task3 started");

    }
}
```

Comment: So what is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is very common to what you would see in a primitive game engine. You need a world "clock" with some level of granularity and you handle each event within each "tick".

You already known your granularity needs to be the least common denominator among your intervals (in this case 0.1). Then a primitive solution would include counters for each task along with a threshold.

Ex (pseudo code):

```
private const double TICK = 0.1;
private double TASK_1_THRESHOLD = 0.1;
private double TASK_1_COUNT = 0.0;
private double TASK_2_THRESHOLD = 2.1;
private double TASK_2_COUNT = 0.0;
private double TASK_3_THRESHOLD = 3.1;
private double TASK_3_COUNT = 0.0;

    private void tick()
{
   TASK_1_COUNT += TICK;
   TASK_2_COUNT += TICK;
   TASK_3_COUNT += TICK;

   if (TASK_1_COUNT >= TASK_1_THRESHOLD) {
       TASK_1_COUNT = 0.0;     
       task1();
     }
    // do this for each
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for your valuable inputs.

Comment: Hope it's helpful. Please mark it as the correct answer if it suits you.